# Flask Restful project structure

Tags: flask, project-structure, flask-restful

This is my current structure:

```
├── app
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   └── resources.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── app.db
├── config.py
├── env
└── run.py
```

Auth module should take care of all the token based authentication.
In order to to this I followed a resource based structure. I created models.py that contain a User model class, and a resources file with all the HTTP methods. Is this the right way to do it? Where should I implement functions like generate_auth_token(), inside models or resources?

Is there a better implementation?

Comment: Voted to close as primarily opinion based.

Comment: I would like to hear more opinions

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.